# Mysql to Rails SQL query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How would I recreate the following query in Rails speak so that it returns the amount of rows processed?

```
self.connection.execute('DELETE FROM `cd_artist`
LEFT JOIN `cdpedia` ON cd_artist.id = cdpedia.`artistId`
WHERE artistId IS NULL;')
```

I realize I should use something like `Artist.find_by_sql` for it to return something, but that gives me an error.

Perhaps there is a more elegant way of doing this?

I want to avoid the Rails way of first searching the database, then grabbing the IDs and deleting the entries with `Object.destroy` or even `Object.delete(id)` since a SQL call is so much faster (if you have the right indexes), but I'm curious as to what the "proper" way to do it is.

Comment: Your query seems to be wrong. Have you already tested it directly on your database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to replace **execute** by **delete**, and it will return the number of rows affected.

```
self.connection.delete('DELETE FROM `cd_artist`
LEFT JOIN `cdpedia` ON cd_artist.id = cdpedia.`artistId`
WHERE artistId IS NULL;')
```

There is maybe a more elegant way to do this with ActiveRecord, but I doubt it will be as efficient as a raw SQL query.

Comment: Thanks. So just use delete and also include the DELETE inside the query? I'm guessing `connection.delete` simply returns the number of rows affected (regardless of the actual query) and execute does not?

Comment: @kakubei Yes you have to include the keyword DELETE, because the query won't be analyzed. So if you put an UPDATE statement, delete() won't see any difference (as you said). execute() however will return a result for select statements and nil for insert/update/delete.